# div getting appended to each other on each interval instead of replacing the earlier divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, setinterval

```
function rows(n,b) {
  for (i of datas[n]) {
    let td = document.createElement("td");
    let charr = i.split("");
    charr.forEach((e, i) => {
     function wait(){
      setTimeout(() => {
        newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.setAttribute("class", "newDiv");
        newDiv.innerHTML = e;
        //newDiv.classList.add("flip");
        td.appendChild(newDiv);
      }, 100*i);
     }
     //setInterval(function(){wait()},2000)
      Trow[b].appendChild(td);
    });
  }
}
```

On each setInterval the set of rows is getting appended to each other side by side instead of replacing the earlier div. I tried using the replaceChild() method but it does not affect my code. Since I am a beginner I have no idea how to figure this out. If you need any more details regarding the question please let me know. Please help. I have also provided an[[image: on 2nd interval call1st interval call] image of what's happening.

Comment: `replaceChild` or `replaceWith` is a way to go. `appendChild` appends a child

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I tried using replace child but it's not having any effect on the code.

Comment: You should show how you try to do it

Comment: Its not obvious what your intentions are.  The code is doing what its been told - to append a new div.  Normally you would have a div there with a unique id and you would set its innerHtml to the new contents.

Comment: @RohitGupta well I am asking if there is any way I meant instead of appending each row side by side I want to replace the 1st row of divs with the 2nd one and 2nd with 3rd and so on tried using replaceChild but it's not having any effect.